# How to bind the datacontext of a tabcontrol content to an instance of an viewmodel in a observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, datacontext

I want to bind the content of my `TabControl` to an instance of my `StepViewModel` in a `ObservableCollection` Steps.

My ProcessViewModel:

```
pubic class ProcessViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<StepViewModel> Steps
    {
        get { return _steps; }
        set { _steps = value; OnPropertyChanged("Steps"); }
    }
    public StepViewModel SelectedStep
    {
        // like above...
    }
}
```

My StepViewModel (DataContext should be the StepVMs in Steps of ProcessVM):

```
public class StepViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get {...} set {...} }
    public object Media { get {...} set {...} }
    //...
}
```

My TabControl (DataContext is ProcessViewModel):

```
<C1:C1TabControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStep}"
    SelectionChanged="{tcSteps_OnSelectionChanged">
           <C1:C1TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:StepView
                        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vmns:ProcessViewModel}}, Path=SelectedStep}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    </local:StepView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </C1:C1TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</C1:C1TabControl>
```

The Compiler delivers the following output message:

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'SelectedStep' property not found on 'object' ''StepViewModel'
>   (HashCode=32952144)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedStep;
>   DataItem='StepViewModel' (HashCode=32952144); target element is
>   'StepView' (Name='StepView'); target property is 'DataContext' (type
>   'Object')"

Does anyone know how I can solve the?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a property named SelectedStep defined in StepViewModel ?

Comment: Looks like there is an issue in the C1TabControl such that it's not binding the data context as you expect. This is shown in the error in that binding is trying to locate a "SelectedStep" property on the "StepViewModel" instead of the "ProcessViewModel". In short, see how the ```C1TabControl.SelectedItem``` property is used within the control.

Comment: `vmns:ProcessViewModel` is not part of the visual tree, so you can't use AncestorType to find it. What you can do with AncestorType is find the *control* whose `DataContext` is `vmns:ProcessViewModel`, which appears to be your tab control: `DataContext="{Binding DataContext.SelectedStep, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type C1:C1TabControl}}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there could be a few small issues with the RelativeSource on your DataContext binding for the StepView. Since the template is not part of the visual tree, I don't think you can use FindAncestor. You can use a StaticResource as a pointer to your main DataContext (eg http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27432/Artificial-Inheritance-Contexts-in-WPF), but I think it might be simpler to just search by ElementName instead in this case. That method would look something like this:

**Update your TabControl to have a name, so it is searchable in bindings by ElementName**

```
<C1:C1TabControl
    x:Name="MyTabControl"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStep}"
    SelectionChanged="{tcSteps_OnSelectionChanged">
```

**Update your StepView to look for the TabControl's DataContext by ElementName**

```
    <local:StepView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=DataContext.SelectedStep}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </local:StepView>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you